# subprocess.Popen: 'OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied' only on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, cross-platform, travis-ci

> Code and logs have changed a lot (due to a major rewrite) since the question was asked.

When my code (given below) executes on Windows (both my laptop and AppVeyor CI), it does what it's supposed to do. But on Linux (VM on TravisCI), it throws me a permission denied error.

---

**Error:**

```
$ sudo python3 test.py
Testing espeak4py
Testing wait4prev
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    mySpeaker.say('Hello, World!')
  File "/home/travis/build/sayak-brm/espeak4py/espeak4py/__init__.py", line 35, in say
    self.prevproc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, executable=self.executable, cwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 745, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 1361, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
The command "sudo python3 test.py" exited with 1.
```

---

**Code:**

espeak4py/**init**.py:

```
#! python3
import subprocess
import os
import platform

class Speaker:
    def __init__(self, voice="en", wpm=120, pitch=80):
        self.prevproc = None
        self.voice = voice
        self.wpm = wpm
        self.pitch = pitch
        if platform.system() == 'Windows': self.executable = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/espeak.exe"
        else: self.executable = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/espeak"

    def generateCmd(self, phrase):
        cmd = [
            self.executable,
            "--path=.",
            "-v", self.voice,
            "-p", self.pitch,
            "-s", self.wpm,
            phrase
        ]
        cmd = [str(x) for x in cmd]
        return cmd

    def say(self, phrase, wait4prev=False):
        cmd=self.generateCmd(phrase)
        if wait4prev:
            try: self.prevproc.wait()
            except AttributeError: pass
        else:
            try: self.prevproc.terminate()
            except AttributeError: pass
        self.prevproc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, executable=self.executable, cwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

test.py:

```
#! python3
import espeak4py
import time

print('Testing espeak4py\n')
print('Testing wait4prev')

mySpeaker = espeak4py.Speaker()

mySpeaker.say('Hello, World!')
time.sleep(1)
mySpeaker.say('Interrupted!')
time.sleep(3)

mySpeaker.say('Hello, World!')
time.sleep(1)
mySpeaker.say('Not Interrupted.', wait4prev=True)
time.sleep(5)

print('Testing pitch')

myHighPitchedSpeaker = espeak4py.Speaker(pitch=120)
myHighPitchedSpeaker.say('I am a demo of the say function')
time.sleep(5)

print('Testing wpm')

myFastSpeaker = espeak4py.Speaker(wpm=140)
myFastSpeaker.say('I am a demo of the say function')
time.sleep(5)

print('Testing voice')

mySpanishSpeaker = espeak4py.Speaker(voice='es')
mySpanishSpeaker.say('Hola. Como estas?')

print('Testing Completed.')
```

---

I don't understand why it works only on one platform and not the other.

Travis CI Logs: https://travis-ci.org/sayak-brm/espeak4py

AppVeyor Logs: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/sayak-brm/espeak4py

GitHub: https://sayak-brm.github.io/espeak4py

---

I got the outputs of `ls -l` as @zvone recommended:

```
$ ls -l
total 48
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis   500 Sep 29 20:14 appveyor.yml
drwxrwxr-x 3 travis travis  4096 Sep 29 20:14 espeak4py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 32400 Sep 29 20:14 LICENSE.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  2298 Sep 29 20:14 README.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis     0 Sep 29 20:14 requirements.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis   759 Sep 29 20:14 test.py

$ ls -l espeak4py
total 592
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 276306 Sep 29 20:14 espeak
drwxrwxr-x 5 travis travis   4096 Sep 29 20:14 espeak-data
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 319488 Sep 29 20:14 espeak.exe
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis   1125 Sep 29 20:14 __init__.py
```

Comment: And what does `ls -l espeak` say? Do you have the permission to execute it?

Comment: @zvone Will check that out after next commit.

Comment: @zvone gave output of `ls -l`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the executable you are trying to run:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 276306 Sep 29 20:14 espeak
```

Its permissions are `rw-` read+write for owner (travis), `rw-` read+write for group (travis), and `r--` read for others. There is no permission to execute for anyone.

You have to give `x` (execute) permission to the user under which the script is running. Or give it to everyone:

```
chmod 775 espeak
```

After that, `ls- l` should say:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 travis travis 276306 Sep 29 20:14 espeak
```

Comment: Well, I couldn't figure out where to put it actually, and since it has something to do with code I put it here. I guess I could have put it up on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Checking out your solution... BTW as I'm developing the software in Windows, can I modify Linux permissions on my PC or do I have to use a setup script?

Comment: `chmod` didn't echo anything so I am assuming it worked. But in my script I now get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/travis/build/sayak-brm/espeak4py/espeak4py/espeak'`. That's exactly where the `espeak` is supposed to be.

Comment: `ls -l espeak4py` gives `-rwxr-xr-x 1 travis travis 276306 Sep 30 04:09 espeak`

Comment: @sbrm1 You can set permissions with the client you use to transfer files to the linux machine (e.g. WinSCP). `chmod` does not echo the result, but later `ls` gives new info (I'll update the answer). There is no reason to get `FileNotFoundError` after chmod. Is it still in the same directory?

Comment: I don't use winSCP or upload the files from my computer, the files are pulled directly from a GitHub repo. `ls -l espeak4py` gives `-rwxr-xr-x 1 travis travis 276306 Sep 30 04:09 espeak` as a part of the output. The file is exactly where it needs to be. I checked with `ls`. You can check it yourself with from the link to TravisCI in my question.

Comment: You have to debug this. There is missing information. Maybe the full path is wrong, maybe a permission is missing on the directory. Try `'ls -l /home/travis/build/sayak-brm/espeak4py/espeak4py/espeak'. Try printing the cwd + executable in the script, try `os.path.exists` on the same thing.

Comment: The new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785140/subprocess-popen-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-only-on-linux

Comment: I guess I'll accept your answer as you managed to get rid of the initial error, even though another problem cropped up.

Comment: `ls -l /home/travis/build/sayak-brm/espeak4py/espeak4py/` shows that the file is there...