# Python subprocess call through crontab not working

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, cron

I am using a python 3.6 script in a Raspberry Pi Zero W that contains the following lines:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(['which', 'node'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

nodeCmd = result.stdout.decode("utf-8").replace('\n', '')

print(nodeCmd)

result = subprocess.run([nodeCmd, './script.js'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The script tries to find the node binary and make a call to a js script. When ran manually, the program works OK, but when I schedule the call through crontab, the *nodeCmd* variable appears blank (instead of */usr/local/bin/node*) and I get the following error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: ''
```

What is going on here? Is this a permissions issue?

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777345/subprocess-popen-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied-only-on-linux?rq=1

Comment: What's the result of `sudo which node` ? Is node installed at the system level or inside `$HOME/.nvm` ?

Comment: @JoseKilo /usr/local/bin/node

Comment: @Sach I see, but should I give 'script.js' execution permissions? I though that was not neccesary as the script is running trhough node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason seems to be that crontab has the $PATH variable set to a different value from the user $PATH. To fix it, I just had to set the wanted value in the cron file, just above the schedule lines:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```